# How to show error messages in current notebook?

Tags: warning-messages

I would like Mathematica to print error messages in current notebook together with output.

This is default option in Mathematica, but recently I turned it off somehow. 
Now, I am getting output in the notebook, and all cells with style Message go to this other window called Messages.

How to set this option back?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In version 9 you can select this in the `Preferences>Messages` tab.
[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

For those using old versions of *Mathematica* that do not have that tab you can change these settings in the Option Inspector in the category **Global Options** > **MessageOptions**.

**UPDATE Mar 2018:** In newer versions, there is no "Messages" tab in the "Preferences" dialog. Use the Option Inspector instead (in the format menu or command shift O).

Comment: wow, if I had ver 9. I would have found it.
thanks!

Comment: The "Messages" tab is not there in more recent versions.

Comment: @becko indeed it has been removed. Luckily, the settings possibility in the option inspector mentioned in the answer are still there.

Answer (score 7):

Since things have changed a complete answer with the new setting is in order.

Use the Option Inspector (in the `Format menu` or using the keystroke `command shift O`).

And change the "KernelMessageAction" field to "PrintToNotebook" as follows

[image]